# overcome sqlplus substitution variable value length limitation shell script

Tags: shell, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a requirement to pass >1000 char length argument to sql*plus.

When checked the docs Sql*Plus has a substitution variable value length limitation of 240 chars.It get the following error when i try
string beginning "XXXXXX,..." is too long. maximum size is 239 characters.

Is there any ways to overcome this..??

I am thinking of splitting the input into parts and calling Sql Plus multiple times in loop.

Is this the only way or any other optimal solution is present..??
Here is my code

```
if [ ! "" == "$ship" ];
then
sqlplus -S ${DBUSER}/${DBPASSWD}@${DBWRITE} @close_tpdoc_task.sql $res $comm $ship $id
fi
```

Kindly advice

Comment: How are you calling SQL*Plus within the shell script; is it running a `.sql` script and passing an argument on the command line? You could perhaps use a heredoc or a bin variable but it depends exactly what you're doing, so please show your code.

Comment: hi, i have included the code